# ContextCompat.GetColor not returning Color

Tags: android, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to replace Resources.GetColor with ContextCompat.GetColor but the last one does not return a color and I don't get what should i use instead of Resources.GetColor(which became deprecated from API 23). Can anyone help me (see below what I want to achieve)?

```
Button.SetBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.LightRed));
```

Note that I use Xamarin, but if you have answer in java I can easily adapt it.
Thank you!

Comment: i used it in java , it worked for me  as btn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));

Comment: I already tried like that and didn't worked. I managed to do it with SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.LightRed), but i'm still curious if there what is the problem with the version from the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return a color"? What is the value returned by your call to `ContextCompat.getColor(...)`?

Comment: I expect Android.Graphics.Color as the Resources.GetColor was returning. But now instead of Android.Graphics.Color I get an int from ContextCompat.GetColor.

Comment: Hello @AlexStefan , I'm using Xamarin too, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Hello @YohanDahmani, I used SetBackgroundResource.

Answer (score 2):

ContextCompat just returns an integer representation of your color. You need to convert it to an Android color by splitting its RGB parts up. Use something like this

```
using Android.Graphics;

public static Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
{
    return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
}
```

and in your method

```
btn.SetBackgroundColor(GetColorFromInteger(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.LightRed);
```

Comment: I find this kind of unpractical. Why would they change GetColor return value? If you use that in tons of places it will be harder to do the above version than just replace Resources with ContextCompat(and add context as parameter).

Comment: It is super annoying, don't know why they changed the return value. What would you replace with ContextCompat though? I don't really understand that. Does my solution work for you?`

Comment: Haven't tried it. In this case I did SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.LightRed). I find it more convenient. Also I get the same result.

Comment: Perfect. I might try that as well - seems to be easier.

Comment: `ContextCompat.getColor(...)` resolves the raw color value of the resource specified by the provided resource identifier, converting a ColorStateList to a raw color value if necessary by using the default color. The code provided is *not* equivalent.

Comment: Worked for me in Xamarin.Android .. Thanks

Comment: What's about the color alpha channel?
`Color.Argb(Color.GetAlphaComponent(color), Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I think - and resolved it by adding the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceAsColor")` on top of the method.

The reason is that, in my opinion, Lint does not recognise the new API at this moment, even though it's valid. Both methods return an integer that represents a resolved color. In my tests Resources.GetColor() and ContextCompat.GetColor() return the same value. However, when using the latter I get an error in Android Studio saying:

```
Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(titleColor)`
```

...which does not make sense, because I AM passing a resolved color. It's just an **int**, so how can I be wrong... So in conclusion, I think suppressing the Lint Error is a valid way to handle the situation at the moment.

If you disagree please raise your voice, I'd be interested.